# Use of annotation (org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.Nullable) compiles with Eclipse, not with javac

Tags: java, annotations, javac, nullable, eclipse-jdt

The following code compiles with Eclipse:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target({ TYPE_USE })
public @interface Nullable {
    // This is org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.Nullable
}

class SomeClass {

    private final SomeOtherClass.@Nullable Inner b;

}
```

but it doesn't with Oracle's javac (version 1.8.0_141), that yields the following error:

```
SomeClass.java: error: annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration
```

I bet that javac and Eclipse's compiler differ on the handling of TYPE_USE, but I could not find a workaround so as to keep the annotation in my code (that should compile within Eclipse and with javac). Any clue on this matter ?

Comment: Wouldn't `@Nullable SomeOtherClass.Inner b` be the same and compilable? This is a weird construct, I have never seen.

Comment: `@Nullable SomeOtherClass.Inner b` doesn't compile (using Eclipse Luna), with the following error: `Type annotations are not allowed on type names used to access static members`. If I remember right, it used to compile at some point in the past, and we had to switch to the weird syntax when updating Eclipse (we develop Eclipse plugins).

Comment: Your code doesn't compile because it is missing import statements, a declaration of `SomeOtherClass`, etc.  Please provide a MWE, preferably without dependence on Eclipse libraries.  When I expanded your code to add the missing parts, it compiled for me with `javac 1.8.0_131`, but maybe there is some difference in your code or your environment.

Comment: The syntax suggested by @Seelenvirtuose was legal with version 1.x of JDT's null annotations (which are pre-Java-8 declaration annotations). The new syntax is required for TYPE_USE annotations as per JSR 308. The reported compile error can be reproduced if either TYPE_USE is unresolved or replaced with ElementType.FIELD or such, i.e., whenever javac sees the annotation as a declaration annotation (and then ecj will complain, too). All this is to be expected.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Stephan Herrmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4611488/stephan-herrmann), I've found the issue. The javac build was using the version of org.eclipse.jdt.annotation declared in our META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file: 1.1.0. But this version is erroneous and this isn't caught when using Eclipse' compiler, as the code is compiled against version 2.0.0 (shipped with the jdt in Eclipse Luna). Specifying version 2.0.0 for the javac build solved the problem.